# Add another feature image box

Tags: posts, images, post-thumbnails

I already have featured image box in my wp theme.

So what I want:

I want to add another featured image box at the top of my category section with different name something like custom featured image.

Why I want to do:

I want to do so because I want to use another featured image box for a specific purpose.

But don`t want to use any plugin please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it by using custom fields with out any plugin. Thanks to [Tania Rascia](https://www.taniarascia.com/wordpress-part-three-custom-fields-and-metaboxes/) Custom field post.